# synaptic cannot access repositories

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.10

thanks for the help

I have had trouble updating for ages, but only just got round to checking it. Updated to Ubuntu 10.10 Maverick at Christmas 2010.

The essential problem is synaptic (or update manager) won't talk to the repository.

I get:

Failed to fetch http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/...ck/Release.gpg
Failed to fetch http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/...slation-en.bz2
Failed to fetch http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/...tion-en_IE.bz2
Failed to fetch http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/...slation-en.bz2
Failed to fetch http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/...tion-en_IE.bz2
Failed to fetch http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/...slation-en.bz2
Failed to fetch http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/...tion-en_IE.bz2
Failed to fetch http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/...slation-en.bz2
Failed to fetch http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/...tion-en_IE.bz2
Failed to fetch http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/...es/Release.gpg
Failed to fetch http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/...slation-en.bz2
Failed to fetch http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/...tion-en_IE.bz2
....,

I have truncated the above.
When I go through these manually on the heanet.ie server, I can't find these files. it's not surprising because these files are not there ... instead there are file with en_GB and en_US suffixes. Why is synaptic appending IE suffixes
 to the query for the server?

However, even when I reset my sources file to contain just these:

deb http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick main universe restricted multiverse
deb http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates universe main multiverse restricted
deb http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-proposed universe main multiverse restricted
deb http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-security universe main multiverse restricted
deb http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-backports main multiverse restricted universe
deb-src http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick main universe restricted multiverse
deb-src http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-security universe main multiverse restricted
deb-src http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates universe main multiverse restricted
deb-src http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-proposed universe main multiverse restricted
deb-src http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-backports universe main multiverse restricted
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick main #Third party developers repository

I still get the error.

Where has the system got these filenames stored or where is it getting these aberrant filenames from? Is it generating them from system or BIOS settings? Can I change them so i can update from the HEANET server again?

Thanks

Apologies if this is not quite appropriate for this forum. I'm usually asking data munging questions not Admin rubbish

Rosser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing them from `ie.archive.ubuntu.com` to just `archive.ubuntu.com`

Possible the server you are connecting to is out.

Comment: NAh, the HEANET .ie server is there I can access the server through the http:// connection it isn't that. Tried other servers. The problem is the aberrant filenames, which seem to be appending _IE when there exist only _GB and _US versions

Comment: Try apt-get with the verbose flag: `sudo apt-get -v install package`  If that doesn't work, it's probably your locale. I forget how to change locale in ubuntu but it's probably somewhere in the system menu.